# creating a view from multiple tables with no like columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am working on a homework question and am stumped. Here is the question:

4. Create a view named **OrderItemProducts** that returns columns from the Orders, OrderItems, and Products tables.
   This view should return these columns from the Orders table: OrderID, OrderDate, TaxAmount, and ShipDate.
   This view should return these columns from the OrderItems table: ItemPrice, DiscountAmount, FinalPrice (the discount amount subtracted from the item price), Quantity, and ItemTotal (the calculated total for the item).
   This view should return the ProductName column from the Products table.

Here is what I have and the error that I am getting is **'Invalid column name FinalPrice'**

```
USE th0664920
GO
CREATE VIEW Order_Item_Products
AS
SELECT o.OrderID, o.OrderDate, o.TaxAmount, o.ShipDate, p.ProductName
FROM Orders AS o, Products AS p
GO
SELECT ItemPrice, DiscountAmount, (ItemPrice - DiscountAmount) AS
FinalPrice, Quantity, (FinalPrice + TaxAmount) AS ItemTotal
FROM OrderItems, Orders;
```

I don't want anyone to write this for me, but I want help to understand what I am doing wrong to get that error. Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to join the tables( probably on order id, and product Id). And then only select the columns you need in the view

Comment: There are no columns that are the same in any of the three tables used for this view. That is partly what is confusing me. :(

Comment: Thanks for the edit by the way! :) How did you get it to look like that?

Comment: Post your table  schema. But I am guessing you have productID to join with products.id ? Or similar.

Comment: You get it to look like that by putting 4 spaces before each line of code.

Comment: @DanBracuk That is not correct.  You format as code.

Comment: Apparently, I have not been looking at enough information. I can join the Orders table with the OrderItems table (both have OrderID) and I can join the OrderItems table and the Products table (both have ProductID)

Answer (score 0):

A couple problems

on the first
use a join not from table, table syntax
there needs to be a join condition(on) - most likely productID

on the second
not sure

a view should be a single query

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with your query, but by your own admission, you are just getting started.  The specific error you are getting is because the database engine you are using does not allow you to use an alias in the select clause the way you are trying.  Specifically, you have this:

```
SELECT ItemPrice
, DiscountAmount
, (ItemPrice - DiscountAmount) AS FinalPrice
, Quantity
, (FinalPrice + TaxAmount) AS ItemTotal
```

`FinalPrice` is an alias, not a column.  Most database engines will throw an error, as did the one you are using.  You have to repeat the calculation.  In other words, this:

```
, (FinalPrice + TaxAmount) AS ItemTotal
```

must be this

```
, (ItemPrice -DiscountAmount + TaxAmount) AS ItemTotal
```

Comment: Is there going to be an error thrown if I put the calculation for the FinalPrice? I am supposed to return both

Comment: Can I use SELECT INTO to put all of the columns that i will need into one of the 3 tables?